# How to proceed if I've found out the answer to my original question but want to push it further

Tags: discussion

In my MathOverflow question [Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem and Ergodic Decomposition Theorem for Continuous-Time Markov Processes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178700/birkhoff-ergodic-theorem-and-ergodic-decomposition-theorem-for-continuous-time-m), I have asked two (related) questions. The first of these essentially takes the form "Will such-and-such a limit always exist, as one would expect?"

Now I have found out the answers to both my questions. In particular, the answer to my first question is "yes" - but I realise that I did not ask the right question here. I should have asked the *stronger* question, "Will such-and-such a limit always exist, and *be equal to* what one would expect?"

How should I proceed? The two options that I am thinking of are:

1. Write as a *comment* what the answers to my two original questions are, and edit the question so that it now asks the stronger version of my first question.
2. Write as an *answer* what the answers to my two original questions are, and then create a new question asking the stronger version of my first question.

(Intuitively, option 1 seems more correct to me, but I am not sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend 2.

Option 2 yields a matching  question-answer pair, easily findable through search.

Option 1 yields a comment which matches some previous form of the question, that someone would have to dig out from  revision history. Not search-friendly at all.

That said: regarding the use of MathOverflow, it's best to ask MathOverflow users on their meta. This is not a typical SE site, and their practices are not always SE practices.

Comment: Thanks for this. Presumably it's fine for me to just copy and paste the content of this question straight into a MathOverflowMeta question (and perhaps mention that I have already asked the question here and was recommended to ask it there)?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can copy-paste your text anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I started typing the question in MathOverflow Meta, it came up with a "related question" http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1922/found-an-answer-to-my-question-and-want-to-change-my-question-accordingly, which seems to be basically the same as my question! (So I don't think I need to ask the question after all.)

Answer (score 0):

Write a new and more precisely worded question.